# Get random value from mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I currently have a MongoDB database which has a collection named words which contains mango and apple for example. How can I get these randomised within my program. This needs to be implemented in the chooseRandomWord() method. Currently when running the application the output is "The chosen word is: com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8AggregateIterableImpl@2bbf4b8b
". I need to choose any random item from that collection. The values apple and mango in my database are called "name". All the code is below:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Game {
    MongoClient client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("chosenWord");
    MongoCollection<Document> wordCollection = database.getCollection("words");
    //Player empty objects
    private final Player playerOne;
    private final Player playerTwo;
    private static final int maxScore = 5;
    private static String chosenWord;
    //Default is true but can alter BEFORE initialization of class
    public static Boolean canStartGame = true;
    //TODO: Try to get these from MongoDB?
    String[] words = new String[]
            {"banana", "apple", "pineapple",
                    "mango", "oranges", "watermelon"};

    public Game(Player playerOne, Player playerTwo) {
        this.playerOne = playerOne;
        this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
        //Set up chosen word and display
        init();

        if (canStartGame)
            startMakingMoves();
    }

    private void init(){
        //Get chosen word from chooseRandomWord
        chosenWord = chooseRandomWord();
        display(chosenWord);
    }

    //Players start making moves
    private void startMakingMoves(){
        makeMove();
    }

    //Display given word
    private void display(String chosenWord){
        System.out.println("The chosen word is: " + chosenWord);
    }

    //TODO: Write test for getting random word
    public String chooseRandomWord() {
        wordCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1)));
        return wordCollection.toString();
        //int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(words.length);
        //return words[randomNumber];
    }

    private void makeMove() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= maxScore) {
            //Player One
            System.out.print(playerOne.getName() + "'s move: ");
            playerMove(playerOne);
            if (playerOne.getScore() == maxScore)
                break;

            //Player Two
            System.out.print(playerTwo.getName() +"'s move: ");
            playerMove(playerTwo);
            if (playerTwo.getScore() == maxScore)
                break;

            i++;
        }
    }

    public void playerMove(Player player)  {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String playerGuess = "";

        //System.out.println(b);

        boolean canRun = true;
        while(canRun) {
            playerGuess = scanner.nextLine();
            //TODO: Change this to check playerGuess is not null or a silly value using regex
            if (playerGuess.matches((".*?([a-z_]*\\?+[a-z_]*).*?"))) {
                System.out.println("You must enter a valid guess");
            } else canRun = false;
        }

        if (chosenWord.contains(playerGuess)) {
            int playerScore = player.getScore();
            playerScore++;
            player.setScore(playerScore);
            player.addMatchedWords(playerGuess);
            System.out.println("That's correct, Your score is: " + player.getScore());
            determineWinner(player);
        } else {
            System.out.println("That's incorrect, Your score is: " + player.getScore());
        }
    }

    public String determineWinner(Player player) {
        int playerScore = player.getScore();
        String winnerText = "";

        if (playerScore == maxScore) {
            winnerText = player.getName() + " is the winner!";
            System.out.println(winnerText);
        }
        return winnerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `public String chooseRandomWord() {
 return wordCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))).toString();
}`

Comment: this still appears in console output? The chosen word is: com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8AggregateIterableImpl@2bbf4b8b. The output should be "The chosen word is: apple" or "The chosen word is: mango" in which these both items are coming from my mongodb collection called words

Comment: see what is output before returning like doing `wordCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))).forEach(System.out::println)`. The problem is we can't do toString() directly

Comment: just prints this com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8AggregateIterableImpl@ea1a8d5

Comment: I have done this to show output .foreach is not working, as I cannot put system.out.println in the foreach as you suggested      System.out.print(wordCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))));

Comment: What is the field name in db for words. Can you share sample collection record

Comment: > db.words.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6133fc6ba2bef98a132309d1"), "name" : "mango" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6133fddbe0eb6a6eda5e1181"), "name" : "apple" }

Comment: just shared above the name of each field is "name" I am trying to randomise these so it either selects an mango or a apple

Comment: try now `public String chooseRandomWord() {
 List<String> res = wordCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1)))
 .map(doc -> doc.getString("name"))
 .into(new ArrayList<>())
 .stream()
 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
 .collect(Collectors.toList());

 return res.get(0);
}`

Comment: thanks for the help that works can you please explain this code in depth so i can get an understanding ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236767/discussion-between-navnath-jadhav-and-minal-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String chooseRandomWord() { 
    return wordCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1)))
        .map(doc -> doc.getString("name"))
        .into(new ArrayList<>()).get(0);
}
```